# не получается передать Parcelable объект через StartActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent

Код следующий

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    int ADD_ACTIVITY = 0;
    int UPDATE_ACTIVITY = 1;
    Context mContext;
    TextView textView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        mContext = this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add:
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult (i, ADD_ACTIVITY);
                //updateList();

                return true;
            case R.id.action_search:
                int s=0;
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "requestCode = " + requestCode + ", resultCode = " + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Exercise myObj = (Exercise) getIntent().getParcelableExtra( Exercise.class.getCanonicalName());
            //String s = myObj.exercise.toString()+myObj.description.toString();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "myObj: " + myObj.exercise + ", " + myObj.description);
            textView.setText("проблемка");
        }
    }

}
```

Вторая активити

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
  Button add;
    TextView textView;
    private long MyDataID;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getParcelableExtra");


        add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        add.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Exercise myObj = new Exercise(1,"ex", "desc");
                textView.setText(myObj.id+myObj.exercise+myObj.description);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(Exercise.class.getCanonicalName(), myObj);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

описание объекта, который передаем

```
public class Exercise implements Parcelable {

    final static String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public String exercise;
    public String description;
    public long id;

    // обычный конструктор
    public Exercise(long _id, String _exersise, String _description) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyObject()");
        id = _id;
        exercise= _exersise;
        description = _description;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // упаковываем объект в Parcel
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "writeToParcel");
        parcel.writeLong(id);
        parcel.writeString(exercise);
        parcel.writeString(description);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Exercise> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Exercise>() {
        // распаковываем объект из Parcel
        public Exercise createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "createFromParcel");
            return new Exercise(in);
        }

        public Exercise[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Exercise[size];
        }
    };

    // конструктор, считывающий данные из Parcel
    private Exercise(Parcel parcel) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyObject(Parcel parcel)");
        id = parcel.readInt();
        exercise = parcel.readString();
        description = parcel.readString();

    }

    public long getID () {return id;}
    public String getExercise(){return  exercise;}
    public String getDescription(){return description;}
}
```

и, собственно, ЛОГ:

```
04-22 15:52:23.664    1207-1207/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29 D/myLogs﹕ MyObject()
04-22 15:52:23.674    1207-1207/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29 D/myLogs﹕ writeToParcel
04-22 15:52:24.164    1207-1207/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29 D/myLogs﹕ requestCode = 0, resultCode = -1
04-22 15:52:24.214    1207-1207/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-22 15:52:24.214    1207-1207/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a38ba8)
04-22 15:52:24.434    1207-1207/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alexsimon.lesson29, PID: 1207
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.alexsimon.lesson29/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.alexsimon.lesson29.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:66)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 15:52:28.574    1207-1207/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1207 SIG: 9
```

Comment: parcel.writeLong(id); id = parcel.readInt(); не смущает? Как у вас дела с размерами типов данных? Не чувствуете разницу между int и long?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте конструктор без параметров:

```
public Exercise() {
}
```

исправьте в другом конструкторе чтение из `Parcel`

`id = parcel.readInt();`

на `id = parcel.readLong();`

Comment: @andreycha исправил, ошибка осталась. Ошибки в логе те же, извиняюсь заранее за формат :java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.example.alexsimon.lesson29/.MainActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.alexsimon.lesson29/com.example.alexsimon.lesson29.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.alexsimon.lesson29.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:66)

Comment: @DeKaNszq не совсем понятно для чего нужен конструктор без параметров? он же нигде использован не будет

Comment: @Алексей конструктор по умолчанию может использоваться системой для пересоздания некоторых объектов. Порпробуйте использовать константу вместо `Exercise.class.getCanonicalName()`

Answer (score 0):

Читаешь int, а записываешь long

```
private Exercise(Parcel parcel) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyObject(Parcel parcel)");
            id = parcel.readInt();
            exercise = parcel.readString();
            description = parcel.readString();

        }

public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "writeToParcel");
        parcel.writeLong(id);
        parcel.writeString(exercise);
        parcel.writeString(description);

    }
```